# Support for Java Decompiling in current Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, decompiling

I am currently looking for the latest version of the decompiler plugin for Eclipse (Kepler). Does this tool still exist?

I have downloaded `jd.ide.eclipse.feature_0.1.5.jar` and placed it in my plugins folder for eclipse but it does not seem to work. I have also copied `JAD.exe` into my local file and I point to that location for Path to Decompiler in JadCliple preferences. I have also set File Associations to read *.class as JadClipse Class File Viewer to default. Is there something else I am missing here? I have read past posts on this website and I see that access to the website has been the main problem. If anyone can guide me in the right direction this would be great.

I keep getting this error, `The Class File Viewer cannot handle the given input ('org.eclipse.ui.ide.FileStoreEditorInput').`

Comment: The FileStoreEditorInput message means that the editor can only deal with files in the Eclipse workspace and not files in the general file system.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for your response. I actually now tried to open a file within the workspace and this is the error I get which is slightly different: The Class File Viewer cannot handle the given input ('org.eclipse.ui.part.FileEditorInput').

Comment: That suggests it is something else about the file the editor does not like, I can't tell what that be from the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using JD-GUI or other GUI based tools, you may want to consider command-line decompilers that are frequently updated like the ones below:

[Procyon](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/wiki/Java%20Decompiler)

[CFR](http://www.benf.org/other/cfr/)

Both of these (should) support new Java 8 additions and other things that JD-GUI usually fails on.